# Print part before matched string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to use grep and print the part that comes before (left) the match between two string and I only want to consider cases where the whole string1 is matching string2.

In red: my strings in file1
[image]

the strings are stored in file1 and file2. 
I am using grep -f to highligh the string.

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

file1

```
ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU
....
```

file1

```
ACUGUACGCGCTATACACUGCCUUGCACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGCGGC
CUGCGCAAGGGCTCUACUGCCUUGCUCUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCUCUGCGCAAATGAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
UGGAAUGUAGGAAGAAGTTTTGCGAGAGGGGAGAGUAUGUAUUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAUUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU
```

Comment: post the grep command you tried along with an example in text form.

Comment: why don't you use `sed` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while read pattern; do sed -n 's/'"${pattern}"'.*//p' file2; done < file1
```

What we're doing here is performing a `sed` command for each pattern in `file1`. In each sed command, we check for the given pattern in the line, and if it has it we replace the pattern and everything after it with nothing (leaving only what was before the pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the solution by RevolutionTech, you can make use of `grep` with a look ahead:

```
while read -r line
do
    grep -Po "^\w*(?=$line)" f2
done < f1
```

This loops through the content of `file1` and, for each line, `grep`s `file2`.

See a basic example of look ahead: let's print the word appearing just before the text `hello` is found:

```
$ echo "this is aahello" | grep -Po '\w*(?=hello)'
aa
```

#### Test

```
$ while read line; do grep -Po "^\w*(?=$line)" f2; done < f1
ACUGUACGCGCTATACACUGCCUUGC
CUGCGCAAGGGCTCUACUGCCUUGCU
UGGAAUGUAGGAAGAAGTTTTGCGAGAGGGGAGAGUAUGUAUUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU
```